# Should becomeFirstResponder() always be called on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift

Should becomeFirstResponder() always be called on the main thread?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.inputBarView.placeholderTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

I've fixed a flickering problem and the animation became smoother after I've made sure the method being called on the main thread.

However, I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: There's nothing that says it should *always* be called on the main thread but there is something in the documentation that says that that method should only be called on a view that is part of an active view hierarchy. See this for more details https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder but like it would also be helpful if you showed the code for the animation as well because there could be an underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whats probably making your animation smoother is not the fact that you call `becomeFirstResponder` in the main thread but probably because the animation that is being triggered when your `placeholderTextView` becomes first responder is being executed on the main thread.

Instead of calling `becomeFirstResponder` in your main thread you should ensure that all animations and UI updates are made in the main thread, not the functions that trigger those changes.