# iOS 11 - Become First Responder not opening the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I am using swift 2.2 for an iOS app.

I have a UIButton with a `.TouchUpInside` event that triggers a `UITextField` to become `first responder`.

Below is the input:

```
    self.manualInput = BrandTextField(y: 0, parentWidth: self.view.frame.width)
    self.manualInput.returnKeyType = .Search
    self.manualInput.autocorrectionType = .No

    self.manualInput.hidden = true
    self.manualInput.text = ""
    self.manualInput.delegate = self
    self.manualInput.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
    self.manualInput.moveX(0)
    self.manualInput.changeWidth(self.view.frame.width)
    self.manualInput.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    self.backgroundView.addSubview(self.manualInput)
```

Below is the button:

```
self.keyboardButton = ActionButton(x: Dimensions.xScaleValue(170), y: Dimensions.yScaleValue(495), onTitle: "Enter code", offTitle: "Enter code", onImage: "manual_entry", offImage: "manual_entry", imageOn: true, action: {
    self.manualInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    print("Open the input")
})
self.backgroundView.addSubview(self.keyboardButton)
```

I also have these two observers:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillShow), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard will show")
    let frame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    self.manualInput.moveY(frame.origin.y - self.manualInput.frame.height)
    self.manualInput.hidden = false
}

func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard will hide")
    self.manualInput.moveY(0)
    self.manualInput.hidden = true
}
```

The problem is that when I press the button as of iOS 11, the becomeFirstResponder() line gets hit, but no keyboard is displayed.

The weird thing for me here is that if I initialise the input inside the view and make it not hidden that the button still does not work. Unless I click on the input, close the keyboard and THEN use the button to trigger.

I don't know if I am missing something in the set up of this for iOS 11 or if I can just no longer do this?

Comment: does this happen on the device or the simulator ?

Comment: Hi, this happens on the simulator and device.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm facing this issue .. it sounds a bug in iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured `becomeFirstResponder` to be called in the main thread?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.manualInput.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

I have faced the similar situation and after I do as above it works properly.

- refer: [Should becomeFirstResponder() always be called on the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769182/should-becomefirstresponder-always-be-called-on-the-main-thread)